# Accessing Marionette's ItemView elements inside CompositeView

Tags: javascript, marionette

This question relates to Marionette.js 
 
Lets say I have an ItemView: `ItemView1` which renders a template with a 
`<div id="div1itemview">`

In a CompositeView: `CompositeView1`, I have a template which has a 
`<div id="div1CompositeView">` 
 CompositeView1 also has `itemView: ItemView1`

I am defining CompositeView1 and ItemView1 in such a way that the final html will be:

```
<div id="div1CompositeView">

    Outer div for doing things

    <div id="div1ItemView">

        Inner div for doing things

    </div>

</div>
```

My question is: Can we access `"click #div1ItemView"` event inside CompositeView1? 
 
Put in another way - Do we have access to (child) ItemView elements inside the (parent) CompositeView?

(Does the same hold true for a CollectionView and its ChildView?) 
 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elements of ItemView can be accessed by the parent CompositeView simply by using their (elements of ItemView's) id in the CompositeView.

Corollary: Events pertaining to ItemView elements can be triggered inside the parent CompositeView!

Answer (score 1):

A more robust approach would be to have the `CompositeView` listen for an event dispatched from the `ItemView` using [`triggers`](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.1/marionette.collectionview.html#childview-event-bubbling-from-child-views):

```
var MyItemView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    triggers: {
        'click': 'do:something'
    }
});

var compositeView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    childView: MyItemView,
    onChildviewDoSomething: function () {
        console.log('do something');
    }
});
```

[`childEvents`](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.1/marionette.collectionview.html#collectionviews-childevents) are another, similar option.